# Counting Principles. Selecting, while having constants

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of five people is to be selected from a class of 12 boys and 9 girls. How many such committees include at least one girl?
Can't find the right method on other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How many committees can be formed without restriction?
2. How many committees have no girls?

Subtract 2 from 1 to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.